# How to store a value to a variable when a user reacts to a message?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have figured out how to do make a bot react with its message from the following code:

```
if(message.content === "!start"){
        message.channel.send(serve).then(message => {
            message.react('764193096060764211');
        })
}
```

(serve is an embed stored in a variable)

I want the user to react with it and the bot to do something with that information, for an example, storing the value 1 to a variable called startingServe. If the user doesn't react within 5 seconds, I want the bot to message "Gamer Ended". How do I do this? Looking forward for the help from this community! If there's anything else needed from me to answer this question, it is fine to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
var startingServe = 0
message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 5000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();
        if (reaction.emoji.id == "764193096060764211") {
            startingServe = 1
        } else {
            message.channel.send('Gamer Ended')
        }
    })
    .catch(collected => {
        message.channel.send('Gamer Ended');
    });
```

Source and more info on [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions) guide page.